# Ruby: Avoid long nested module when reference to constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, constants

I have a class that define a constant in my rails app. For example:

```
module A
 module B
   class C
     CONSTANT = "constant"
   end
 end
end
```

And then, in another module, I want to get this constant:

```
module Test
  class Main
    def get_constant
       const = A::B::C::CONSTANT
    end
  end
end
```

This is too long and verbose. I tried some ways for not using prefix `A::B::C`. for example:

```
module Test
  class Main
    include A::B
    def get_constant
       const = C::CONSTANT
    end
  end
end
```

But in all cases, I always meet error because my rails app cannot find this constant. Please tell me how

Comment: you can use `def get_constant; C::CONSTANT; end`

Answer (score 1):

In the second class/module, you can create a reference to the constant from the first:

```
class One
  OneConst = 1
end

class Two
  TwoConst = One::OneConst
  def self.two_const
    TwoConst
  end
  def two_const
    TwoConst
  end
end

puts Two.two_const
puts Two.new.two_const
```

Comment: I can apply your first solution. it means put scope no another variables:   `TwoConst = One::OneConst`. In the second example I cannot apply because: 1. must extend module (but my variables are inside class). 2. In case I extend module, I try reference to this constant using `C::Constant`. I meet error: undefine constant  `C::Constant`

Comment: You're right, the second didn't work. that's weird, i thought it did the first time.